# User login is not working properly in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication

I am trying to make a login process in Nodejs  for my Angular site, **when user login it send some data like - username, userid and token**, so I am trying when user login and **if Userid is not found the user should be logout automatic** from the page/website. How should I approach to do this ?

**login.service**

```
    connection.query(sql,[email,password], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      res.send({
        "code":400,
        "failed":"error ocurred"
      })
    }else{
      if(results.length >0){
        console.log(results.length);
        if(results[0].password == password){

          const payload = {
            admin: email
          };
          var token = jwt.sign(payload, app.get('superSecret'), {
            expiresIn : 60*60*24 // expires in 24 hours
          });
          res.send({
            "code":200,
            token : token,
            result : email,
            username: results[0].fullname,
            clientid : results[0].clientid,
            userid: results[0].id,
            "success":"1"
          });
        }
        else{
          res.send({
            "code":204,
            "success":"Email and password does not match"
          });
        }
      }
      else{
        res.send({
          "code":204,
          "success":"Email does not exits"
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You should change the status sent by the result if the email or the password does not match to 404 or 401 instead of 204! then it will be caught in your subscription error handler and make the scenario that you want to do

Comment: @RebaiAhmed mind to elaborat pls ?